# Exception thrown while trying to run sql through c#

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to run a database query through c#. I am trying to pass a parameter into my sql statement but I am getting an exception saying invalid near @Agent_ID. 
 My code is like this

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select Csr_DISBURSEMENTDATE, Csr_AGENTNUMBER, Csr_TOTCURREARNINGS, Csr_MISCADJUSTMENTS, Csr_YTDTOTALCOMM, Csr_PAYMENTMETHOD From Cm_Opt_Csr_CommStatement_S " +
                        "inner join Cm_Opt_Con_Contract_S on Con_WritingCode = Csr_AgentNumber" +
                        "inner join Cm_Opt_Agt_Agent_S on agt_ID = Con_AgentID" +
                        "where Agt_ID = @AgentID");
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgentID", Con_agentID);
                    command.Connection = conn;
                    SqlDataReader rdr = null;
                    rdr = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Con_agentID is a guid and in the database table the column which it maps to is a uniqueidentifer. I am stuck at this point. Could someone please point out the mistake in the syntax.
The exception thrown is

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'Agt_ID'.'
```

Comment: add `space` before `where` and before every keyword like `inner join` also

Comment: Check the query string in the debugger. You have a typo. There's no space between `Con_AgentID` and `where`

Comment: @rene a verbatim string won't help. There's a space missing. Unless you mean "use a verbatim multiline string instead of concatenating lines"

Comment: It looks like you are missing spaces in a couple places.  Try verbatim strings in C# using `@` before the string. This will include all whitespace between lines and not require using `+` so much.

Comment: I suggest you to create procedures for queries like this.

Comment: @Bharadwaj Why is that?

Comment: @Magnus easy to maintain and syntax errors like this won't happen. Consider the case of complex queries. It's difficult to understand `+` concatenated queries inside code and it's difficult to modify also. Chances of getting errors are more

Comment: Typo-closable ? or not Typo-closable? Btw Debugger is an easy and powerfull Tools. please use it, at least once!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing spaces between words when you continue on to next line.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select Csr_DISBURSEMENTDATE, Csr_AGENTNUMBER, Csr_TOTCURREARNINGS, Csr_MISCADJUSTMENTS, Csr_YTDTOTALCOMM, Csr_PAYMENTMETHOD From Cm_Opt_Csr_CommStatement_S " +
                        "inner join Cm_Opt_Con_Contract_S on Con_WritingCode = Csr_AgentNumber " +
                        "inner join Cm_Opt_Agt_Agent_S on agt_ID = Con_AgentID " +
                        "where Agt_ID = @AgentID");
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgentID", Con_agentID);
                    command.Connection = conn;
                    SqlDataReader rdr = null;
                    rdr = command.ExecuteReader();
```